# Avoid reverting to top of page when setting <body> position to fixed with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, scroll

I am using a fixed overlay div on my page to show additional content when the user clicks on a certain button.

The trouble with this is that on iOS, the content behind tends to scroll rather than the overlay div.

The only effective solution I have found to this is to use jQuery to alter the class of  and toggle its position to fixed (and overflow: hidden) whenever the overlay div is selected to appear (and then back again on closing the overlay). E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#filter-btn, .close-filter").click(function(){
$("body").toggleClass("fix");
});
});
```

Whilst this works, it also causes the content within the body itself to move up to the top of the page when changing to 'fixed' to the top which is monentarily visible whilst the fixed overlay div fades in.

Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Usually just setting body height to 100% and `overflow:hidden` is all that is needed

Comment: Thanks - doesn't seem to work in this instance however.

Comment: did you remove `position:fixed`? Best suggestion is look at other overlays and inspect how they do it... approach is usually the same

Comment: Aha, that did the trick. Honestly thought I'd already tried that, but clearly not. :)

Comment: @J.Doe - Just curious, are you saying setting `height: 100%; overflow: hidden` prevented the body from scrolling up and ALSO prevented content from being scrolled from the overlay (assuming you're at the top/bottom of the overlay and continue swiping/dragging?)

Comment: Jack, yes, I was saying that. However, on closer inspection it would seem that whilst this does stop the scrolling to the top, it doesn't actually prevent the content scrolling underneath the overlay.

Apologies - my bad. :(

Comment: Any news? the body keeps scrolling if `position:fixed` is removed. On the Chrome emulator it doesn't scroll but on iOS real device it does.

Answer (score 0):

This can generally be solved by setting body height to 100% and `overflow:hidden` within the css rule for class applied to the body

Comment: I've tried a few things but this is definately not working. All I can think of is a JS based solution, but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: create demo that replicates this

Comment: but you are using `fixed` for body ...why?

Comment: Simply so that the content behind the overlay does not scroll when it opens up. It's an ios issue I believe.