# JavaScript avoid reset to top of page after position:fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have scroll pagination to my app where I display some images. When I click an image, a modal opens up displaying the image full screen. In order to prevent scroll in the body I provide the following class to `html, body` tags. Problem is that if I scroll down by 40 images select an image and after I close that modal, the images feed starts displaying again from the top of the page. I want to avoid this an continue from the position that I was before clicking that image.

```
.item-mdl-plh {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I have found similar questions to mine here, and implemented this one but it does not work,`scrollTop` always returns 0 from the feed div element.

[How do I prevent custom full screen from resetting the scroll position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597346/how-do-i-prevent-custom-full-screen-from-resetting-the-scroll-position/45598622)

And others in jQuery but did not understand:

[Avoid reverting to top of page when setting <body> position to fixed with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938927/avoid-reverting-to-top-of-page-when-setting-body-position-to-fixed-with-jquery)

I would like to understand how can I achieve this behavior that I want using vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Need some more workable code to analyse the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've decided to use the `scrollTop` method, You can use this.

I don't know why, but `scrollTop` always returns 0 in chrome. But the `pageYOffset` returns the intended value.

So you can use something like this.

```
let scrollTop = 0;

function open_modal() {
    scrollTop = pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0;
    // Modal
}

function close_modal() {
    // Remove modal
    scrollTo(0, scrollTop); // After removing fixed position from body, scroll back to last recorded posititon
}
```